# Is it possible to add content to a global Vue component from a single file comp?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have made a global component that will render the content we want.

This component is very simple

```
<template>
  <section
    id="help"
    class="collapse"
  >
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <slot /> 
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'VHelp',
  };
</script>
```

I use it inside my base template with

```
<v-help />
```

I'm trying to add content to this component slot from another single file component using.

```
<v-help>
  <p>esgssthsrthsrt</p>
</v-help>
```

But this logically create another instance of my comp, with the p tag inside. Not the correct thing I want to do.

So I tried with virtual DOM and rendering function, replacing `slot` by `<v-elements-generator :elements="$store.state.help.helpElements" />` inside my `VHelp` comp.

The store `helpElements` is a simple array with objects inside.

```
{
   type: 'a',
   config: {
     class: 'btn btn-default',
   },
   nestedElements: [
     {
       type: 'span',
       value: 'example',
     },
     {
       type: 'i',
     },
   ],
},
```

Then inside my `VElementsGenerator` comp I have a render function that with render element inside virtual DOM from an object like

```
<script>
  import {
    cloneDeep,
    isEmpty,
  } from 'lodash';

  export default {
    name: 'VElementsGenerator',
    props: {
      elements: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
      },
    },
    methods: {
      iterateThroughObject(object, createElement, isNestedElement = false) {
        const generatedElement = [];

        for (const entry of object) {
          const nestedElements = [];
          let elementConfig = {};

          if (typeof entry.config !== 'undefined') {
            elementConfig = cloneDeep(entry.config);
          }

          if (entry.nestedElements) {
            nestedElements.push(this.iterateThroughObject(entry.nestedElements, createElement, true));
          }

          generatedElement.push(createElement(
            entry.type,
            isEmpty(elementConfig) ? entry.value : elementConfig,
            nestedElements
          ));

          if (typeof entry.parentValue !== 'undefined') {
            generatedElement.push(entry.parentValue);
          }
        }

        if (isNestedElement) {
          return generatedElement.length === 1 ? generatedElement[0] : generatedElement;
        }

        return createElement('div', generatedElement);
      },
    },
    render(createElement) {
      if (this.elements) {
        return this.iterateThroughObject(this.elements, createElement);
      }

      return false;
    },
  };
</script>
```

This second method is working well but if I want to render complex data, the object used inside the rendering function is very very long and complex to read.

So I'm trying to find another way to add content to a global component used inside a base layout only when I want it on a child component.

I can't use this `VHelp` component directly inside children comps because the HTML page architecture will be totally wrong.

I'm wondering if this is possible to add content (preferably HTML) to a component slot from a single file comp without re-creating a new instance of the component?

Furthermore I think this is very ugly to save HTML as string inside a Vuex store. So I don't even know if this is possible and if I need to completely change the way I'm trying to do this.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the store, you should only store data and not an HTML structure. The way to go with this problem would be to store the current state of the content of the v-help component in the store. Then, you would have a single `v-help` component with a slot (like you already proposed). You should pass different contents according to the state in the store. Here is an abstract example:

```
<v-help>
  <content-one v-if="$store.state.content === 'CONTENT_ONE' />
  <content-two v-else-if="$store.state.content === 'CONTENT_TWO' />
  <content-fallback v-else />
</v-help>
```

Child element somewhere else:

```
<div>
  <button @click="$store.commit('setContentToOne')">Content 1</button>
</div>
```

Vuex Store:

```
state: {
  content: null
},
mutations: {
  setContentToOne(state) {
    state.content = 'CONTENT_ONE';
  }
}
```

Of course it depends on your requirements and especially on how many different scenarios are used if this is the best way to achieve this. If I understood you correctly, you are saving help elements to the store. You could also save an array of currently selected help elements in there and just display them directly in the `v-help` component.

---

**EDIT**:

Of course you can also just save the static component (or its name) in the store. Then, you could dynamically decide in the child components, which content is shown in `v-help`. Here is an example:

```
<v-help>
  <component :is="$store.state.helpComponent" v-if="$store.state.helpComponent !== null" />
</v-help>
```

Test Component:

```
<template>
  test component
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'test-component'
};
</script>
```

Child element somewhere else *(variant 1, storing the name in Vuex)*:

```
<div>
  <button @click="$store.commit('setHelpComponent', 'test-component')">Set v-help component to 'test-component'</button>
</div>
```

Child element somewhere else *(variant 2, storing the whole component in Vuex)*:

```
<template>
  <button @click="$store.commit('setHelpComponent', testComponent)">Set v-help component to testComponent (imported)</button>
</template>

<script>
import TestComponent from '@/components/TestComponent';

export default {
  name: 'some-child-component',
  computed: {
    testComponent() {
      return TestComponent;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Child element somewhere else *(variant 3, storing the name, derived from the imported component, in Vuex; **I would go with this variant**)*:

```
<template>
  <button @click="$store.commit('setHelpComponent', testComponentName)">Set v-help component to 'test-component'</button>
</template>

<script>
import TestComponent from '@/components/TestComponent';

export default {
  name: 'some-child-component',
  computed: {
    testComponentName() {
      return TestComponent.name;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Vuex Store:

```
state: {
  helpComponent: null
},
mutations: {
  setHelpComponent(state, value) {
    state.helpComponent = value;
  }
}
```

See also the documentation for dynamic components (`<component :is="">` syntax): https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: Yes this will be working well if I had a default content inside `v-help`. But I everything can be inside `v-help` and I can't know in advance what will be passed to this component. The content is unique on each page this is why I think I can't use the way you explained.

Comment: Okay, and where does this content come from? From a server request or a static vue component?

Comment: This is static content defined on a vue component

Comment: @Jérôme If it is a static component and you need to decide in the child component which component should be used, you can store the name of the component in the store. I've added an example of this.